# How do I authenticate using SimpleSAMLphp within an embedded iframe

Tags: php, session, iframe, x-frame-options, simplesamlphp

We have a platform developed entirely in-house that uses SimpleSAMLphp to authenticate our client's users who may use anything from Azure AD to G-Suite. Pages can be shared allowing our clients to embed an iframe version of the page in a platform of their choosing.

The issue is that Microsoft and Google no longer allow their login pages to appear in an iframe due to same-origin X-Frame-Options and cross-domain iframe security.

The embed URL contains an encrypted organization identifier so that we known which authentication platform to direct them to, but SimpleSAMLphp redirects them to the MS or Google login page and fails to load.

How can I authenticate using SimpleSAMLphp starting within a cross-domain iframe?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to provide a button to the user that would open the standard login page in a new window of its own. Therefore bypassing the cross-browser security.

```js
var mywin;
function login() {
    mywin = window.open("https://my.login.page", "my_win_name", "height=600,width=600");
}
function closewin() {
    mywin.close();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="login()">Login</button>
```

This page performs the login with SimpleSAMLphp then sets an authentication `$_COOKIE`, reloads it's opener using `window.opener.location.reload()`. The iframed page then calls a function onunload `<body onunload="closewin()">` which closes the window.

I found this to be the most useful approach. Calling the login window `onload` caused occasional security alerts, so a user-initiated button seems the most appropriate. Also having the new window close itself after reloading its `opener` left a brief period where the user was looking at nothing at all. Since the iframed page has access to the opened window, it only made sense to wait until it was reloading to close the window, thus `onunload`. Subsequently, if someone manually reloads or navigates away from the contents of the iframe before the login is complete, the corresponding window is closed as well.